# Сомневаюсь в правильности стилистики в предложении

Tags: стилистика, семантика

*Будущей весной волны реки опять и опять напоют свой старый мотив.*

Можно ли не придираться к стилистике этого предложения или что-то обязательно нужно исправить?

Comment: Будущей весной волны реки снова напоют свой старый мотив.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, обязательно надо поправить.  "Опять и опять" - указание на повторяющееся действие, которое плохо сочетается с конкретным временем (будущей весной) и с глаголом "напоют". Как варианты предлагаю:

**Будущей весной волны реки опять напоют свой старый мотив.**

**Будущей весной волны реки станут опять и опять напевать свой старый мотив.**

Второй вариант сохраняет авторское "опять и опять", но его недостаток в том, что остается неясным, почему указано, что это произойдет именно будущей весной.

---

UPD. Вот еще вариант, из которого ясно, что действие повторяется каждую весну:

**И будущей весной волны реки станут опять и опять напевать свой старый мотив.**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и предложенные Вами варианты, М_Г!

Comment: Вновь станут напевать.

Answer (score 1):

Матвей, а что это за текст, если не секрет?

Созданный образ мне неясен совершенно. Весной реки бурные – мотивы и напевы не для них, а летом реки спокойные, не поющие.  "Напевают" что-то постоянное и узнаваемое речки да ручейки, но именно напевают, а не "напоют, помолчат, потом напоют снова".

В общем, загадочное описание: не видно картинки – трудно что-либо поправить.

Comment: Это из рассказика. Я на общественных началах провожу раз в неделю занятия в чём-то наподобие литстудии.

Comment: Не все реки такие бурные весной, что о них нельзя сказать, что они поют. Мое воображение рисует реку, которая то поет, то молчит. Может снег начал таять, а потом вновь ударили заморозки.

Comment: Как интересно! И спасибо за ответ.  Мне кажется, что занятие литературным творчеством - один из лучших способов для изучения языка.

Answer (score 1):

"Будущей весной волны реки опять и опять напоют свой старый мотив".
Рискну предложить ещё один вариант к уже предложенным. Не вижу в нём принципиального различия. Хотелось бы только предостеречь от неоправданного употребления возвратного местоимения "свой". В данном случае его, возможно, стоит оставить: неизвестно ведь, что это за мотив: свой или чужой.
Будущей весной волны реки снова начнут напевать старый мотив.